# Merging images in Python PIL to produce animated gifs

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I've been using ImageMagick for a while to create simple animated gifs that demonstrate how GAN-generated faces (from thispersondoesnotexist dot com) all have a "family resemblance".

The animated gif starts by showing an initial image, progressively merges it with the second image & then progressively demerges it until the second image is shown.

I've used a crude bash script that works fine but is slow, and as I code a lot in Python, I wanted to try to do the same in PIL.

I don't know much about image processing & I'm not a professional programmer.

The bash script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1, $2 are input files, $3 is a string
#
for i in {00..100..05}
    do composite $1 $2 -blend $i  $3_$i.png
done

convert  $3_*png  -set delay 26  animated.gif
```

This creates an animated gif like this

[image: animated gif from ImageMagick]

My first attempt was using PIL.Image.blend() method:

```
from PIL import Image

one = Image.open("somepath/some_jpg1.jpg")
two = Image.open("somepath/some_jpg2.jpg)

img_list = [Image.blend(one, two, i/100) for i in range(0, 105, 5)]

img_list[0].save('test_animation.gif', save_all=True, append_images=img_list[1:], duration=250)
```

This works after a fashion but the images are quite degraded (if it were film I'd call it   "reticulation")

[image]

I've looked at the PIL docs for other methods such as PIL.Image.composite() and PIL.Image.paste() in case there's other ways of doing this, but I can't understand how to create & deploy transparency masks to achieve what I want.

I don't understand how the images appear to be being degraded or how to stop this happening.

Comment: The gif format has a low number of colors, so gif encoders use dithering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither to emulate more colors

Comment: I'm not at a computer to try this, but you could try converting each frame to `P` mode before appending to the sequence to save - that should allow each frame to have its own, optimal palette. Then save as GIF, passing `include_color_table=True` to see if PIL will store each frame with its own, optimal palette.

Comment: I used [Image.blend(one, two, i/100).convert("P") for i in range(0,105,5)] to try that Mark & it doesn't seem to make any difference.   It occurred to me that the bash script creates a disk PNG file for each frame then reads those back in to create the GIF. Those have an RGB colour type while the sequence in the PIL version are each Palette.  But converting (as above) makes no difference either to the end result. The PIL version is always lower quality than the 'native' ImageMagcick version.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the PIL palette optimisation and dither code is not very fancy. GIF is a really terrible image format and getting nice results takes a lot of work, unfortunately.

I realise you asked for PIL solutions, but [pyvips](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips) has a high-quality GIF writer  -- it uses [libimagequant](https://github.com/ImageOptim/libimagequant) (the quantisation and dither library from [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/)) and the results are even better than imagemagick.

I tried:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pyvips

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print(f"usage: {sys.argv[0]} OUTPUT-FILENAME IMAGE1 IMAGE2 ...")
    sys.exit(1)

# load the images at 200 pixels across
# add a copy of the first face to the end, so we loop
faces = [pyvips.Image.thumbnail(filename, 200).copy_memory()
         for filename in sys.argv[2:]]
faces.append(faces[0])

# fade between two images
def fade(a, b):
    # factor is a pecentage, so 20 steps
    frames = [a * (factor / 100) + b * (1 - factor / 100)
              for factor in range(100, 0, -5)]
    return pyvips.Image.arrayjoin(frames, across=1)

# fade between face1 and face2, then between face2 and face3, etc
fades = []
for a, b in zip(faces, faces[1:]):
    fades.append(fade(a, b))

# join all the fades into a single image and save it
pyvips.Image.arrayjoin(fades, across=1) \
    .write_to_file(sys.argv[1], page_height=faces[0].height)
```

If I run like this, using three faces from thispersondoesnotexist:

```
$ ./fade.py x.gif ~/pics/face-*
```

It finishes in about 3 seconds and I get:

[image]

Comment: I use PIL elsewhere for other simple image ops so it was the natural thing to try, but I'm not at all averse to using a different library; I'll check this out properly when I have a minute but I think this looks a good candidate for the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting "pyvips.error.Error: no such operation thumbnail
  VipsOperation: class "thumbnail" not found.  "   ... The latest version of libvips my package manager offers is 8.4.5 so that may have a bearing

Comment: Yes, that's almost six years old now, unfortunately. Is this centos7? Remi Collet maintains a set of RPMs which include the current stable version of libvips https://rpms.remirepo.net/ Or you can build from source yourself of course, it's a fairly easy package to make.

Comment: Well, I managed to build libvips but now I get "pyvips.error.Error: unable to write to file b'../test_vips.gif'
  VipsForeignSave: "../test_vips.gif" is not a known file format
" ... It doesn't seem appropriate to try and debug this in the comments, as it may be just a local problem to my system, so perhaps I'll leave it there

Comment: You're missing cgif, the GIF write library that libvips uses. See https://github.com/dloebl/cgif You'll need libimagequant too, check the output of configure carefully.

Comment: @jcupitt fantastic solution, but can you please show a sample with pictures on local disk? for example the input pictures are in "C:\\Temp\\" etc (the "sys.argv" seems confusing)? Thank you.

Comment: `sys.argv` is just the command-line arguments. You can use an array of local filenames instead.